# chrome spawns "kill pages?" text when nothing is wrong

Tags: windows-7, google-chrome

This is a bit different than other questions about the "kill pages" thing. This has been happening from time to time that the box pops up, lists ALL tabs as non responsive but nothing seems to be wrong when any of them

When it happens the pop up comes up repeatedly with ~ 5-10 second delay when I click "wait" It tends to stop when i navigate away from wherever i am.
Win7 x64

8GB ram

AND Phenom II x4 965 processor

on Wifi

Its not really a big deal just a little odd.

Comment: Too many tabs I suspect.